# What is the reason of this access violation prevented by weird modifications?

Tags: delphi, access-violation

I use seattle in windows 10.

I try to print public ip address and gateway address.

An access violation occurs in the last line.

When I remove line 1 it works well.

```
uses Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.Win.ComObj, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, winapi.iphlpapi, winapi.iptypes, winapi.winsock;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  _IPAdapterAddresses: PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES;
  _SizePointer: Integer;
begin
  Label2.Caption := Label2.Caption + ' ' + IdHTTP1.Get'http://ipinfo.io/ip'); // line 1

  _IPAdapterAddresses := AllocMem(_SizePointer);

  GetAdaptersAddresses(2, 128, nil, _IPAdapterAddresses, @_sizepointer);

  Label1.Caption := Label1.Caption + ' ' + string(inet_ntoa(_IPAdapterAddresses^.FirstGatewayAddress.Address.lpSockaddr.sin_addr)); // access violation
end;
```

When I modify the last line as the following it works well.

```
  Label1.Caption := {Label1.Caption + ' ' + }string(inet_ntoa(_IPAdapterAddresses^.FirstGatewayAddress.Address.lpSockaddr.sin_addr));
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_IPAdapterAddresses := AllocMem(_SizePointer);
```

At this point `_SizePointer` is an uninitialized variable. It's value is indeterminate. Who knows how much memory you allocate? Certainly you don't. Since the value is indeterminate, any change in the code can result in a different value being used.

```
GetAdaptersAddresses(2, 128, nil, _IPAdapterAddresses, @_sizepointer);
```

You fail to check the return value of this call. So you don't know whether or not it succeeds. If the call fails, then you have no grounds for expecting `_IPAdapterAddresses` to contain anything of use. And in any case, you may not have allocated enough memory for `_IPAdapterAddresses`.

On top of all that, you have allocated heap memory and failed to deallocate it, thus leaking it.

You are looking for something along these lines:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.IpHlpApi,
  Winapi.IpTypes,
  Winapi.WinSock,
  Winapi.Windows;

const
  GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_GATEWAYS = $0080;

procedure Main;
var
  Addresses: PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES;
  OutBufLen: ULONG;
  Retval: ULONG;
begin
  OutBufLen := 15*1024; // MSDN recommendation is to use a 15kB buffer
  GetMem(Addresses, OutBufLen);
  try
    Retval := GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_GATEWAYS, nil, Addresses,
      @OutBufLen);
    if Retval = ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW then
    begin
      ReallocMem(Addresses, OutBufLen);
      Retval := GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_GATEWAYS, nil, Addresses,
        @OutBufLen);
    end;
    if Retval <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
      RaiseLastOSError(Retval, '');
    Writeln(inet_ntoa(Addresses^.FirstGatewayAddress.Address.lpSockaddr.sin_addr));
  finally
    FreeMem(Addresses);
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: i set the size as 15,000 according to a similar example here and it works good. i tried to use sizeof but the output was 4. even after i saw the example of msdn which says sizeof(PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES) i couldn't get the size of PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES with delphi. and freed the memory. thanks always david.

Comment: You are asking for the size of a pointer, and since you have a 32 bit process, that is 4. There's no reason whatsoever for you to be trying to query for the size of a memory block, something you cannot do anyway. You just allocated the block, you know how large it is. Also, please please don't use the code in your question. It doesn't check for errors.